# Pinax stripe not allowing me to add payment plans in admin panel

Tags: django, stripe-payments, pinax

I am developing a django application using Pinax Stripe(https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe). I have added the web hooks, test api keys. But when I login into the admin panel and go to 'plans' section to create a plan, in the 'create a plan' page. It doesnt show the text fields for admin to create a plan. Have a I gone wrong with the setup somewhere? I really dont understand this.

Answer (score 0):

To create a plan you have to do the following.

1. Go to the Stripe account settings https://dashboard.stripe.com/account
2. Set up your webhook under the "webhook" tab
3. Go to the Dashboard https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/dashboard
4. On the left side under "subscriptions" go to "plans"
5. Create a plan.
6. Go back to your virtual envrionment and write the following management command in the console`python manage.py sync_plans`

Once this is done you should be able to see your plans. Let me know if that works.